# neo4j save to database and display in neo4j browser java

Tags: java, eclipse, neo4j

I have a java project in eclipse that stores a graph into a Neo4j database like this:

```
Node e = graphDb.createNode(label);
e.setProperty(V_TYPE, PORTFOLIO_V_TYPE);
e.setProperty("Name", "Hey");       
e.setProperty("Code", "My code");
e.setProperty("Idea", "My idea");
porfolios.add(e);
```

(obviously adding way more than just this one and also adding relationships)

MY QUESTION IS! : how can I visualize the resulting graph (in this case just that one node...)? in other words, is there any way to connect to the neo4j browser so that I don't have to make my own UI?
These are my imports:

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Label;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Path;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.ResourceIterator;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.IndexDefinition;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.Schema;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.Evaluators;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.TraversalDescription;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.Traverser;
```

The maven dependency I am using is the:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the database in joava, you also need to enable the BOLT protocol.
You can take a look at the documentation : https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/tutorials-java-embedded/#tutorials-java-embedded-bolt

Firstly import the bolt jar in your project

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-bolt</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

And then configure the database to enable the bolt protocol :

```
GraphDatabaseSettings.BoltConnector bolt = GraphDatabaseSettings.boltConnector( "0" );

GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
        .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( DB_PATH )
        .setConfig( bolt.type, "BOLT" )
        .setConfig( bolt.enabled, "true" )
        .setConfig( bolt.address, "localhost:7687" )
        .newGraphDatabase();
```

At this moment you can take the neo4j desktop version, and create a remote connection, and use the browser.

Comment: So with this I could start the server and view it from there right away?

Comment: with that you enabled the BOLT protocole of Neo4j, s o you can use a Neo4j browser to query and display your query. Neo4j browser is just a client that use the BOLT protocole